# How to move sub child elements of xml to a new xml file using XSLT & Python?

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I have this xml file a.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TestSuite Name="DM123">
  <Group Name="TestRoot" ExecutionPolicy="AnyDeviceAnyOrder">
    <Parameters>
      <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="maxA" Value="1" />
      <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="MaxB" Value="120" />
      <Parameter Type="String" Name="MaxC" Value="integration" />
    </Parameters>
    <Children>
      <Group Name="Cam1">
        <Parameters>
           <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="maxA" Value="1" />
           <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="MaxB" Value="120" />
           <Parameter Type="String" Name="MaxC" Value="integration" />
        </Parameters>
        <Children>
          <Group Name="Field1">
            <Parameters>
              <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="maxA" Value="1" />
              <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="MaxB" Value="120" />
              <Parameter Type="String" Name="MaxC" Value="integration" />
            </Parameters>
            <Children>
              <Test Name="Test1" Namespace="TestCases">
                <Parameters>
                  <Parameter Type="Device" Name="Device">
                    <Requirements>
                      <Requirement TypeId="a76" Source="User" />
                      <Requirement TypeId="2c9" Source="User" />
                    </Requirements>
                  </Parameter>
                </Parameters>
              </Test>
            </Children>
          </Group>
          <Group Name="Field3">
            <Parameters>
              <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="maxA" Value="1" />
              <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="MaxB" Value="120" />
              <Parameter Type="String" Name="MaxC" Value="integration" />
            </Parameters>
            <Children>
              <Test Name="Test5" Namespace="TestCases">
                <Parameters>
                  <Parameter Type="Dev" Name="Dev">
                    <Requirements>
                      <Requirement TypeId="a76" Source="User" />
                      <Requirement TypeId="2c9" Source="User" />
                    </Requirements>
                  </Parameter>
                </Parameters>
              </Test>
            </Children>
          </Group>
          <Test Name="Test6" Namespace="TestCases">
            <Parameters>
              <Parameter Type="Dev" Name="Dev">
                <Requirements>
                  <Requirement TypeId="a76" Source="User" />
                  <Requirement TypeId="2c9" Source="User" />
                </Requirements>
              </Parameter>
              <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="expected amount of images" Value="10" />
            </Parameters>
          </Test>
        </Children>  
      </Group>
    </Children>
  </Group>
  <Models>
    <Model Name="DD1" />
  </Models>
</TestSuite>
```

What i am trying to achieve is output.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TestSuite Name="DM123">
  <Group Name="TestRoot" ExecutionPolicy="AnyDeviceAnyOrder">
    <Parameters>
      <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="maxA" Value="1" />
      <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="MaxB" Value="120" />
      <Parameter Type="String" Name="MaxC" Value="integration" />
    </Parameters>
    <Children>
      <Test Name="Test1" Namespace="TestCases">
        <Parameters>
           <Parameter Type="Device" Name="Device">
             <Requirements>
               <Requirement TypeId="a76" Source="User" />
               <Requirement TypeId="2c9" Source="User" />
             </Requirements>
           </Parameter>
        </Parameters>
      </Test>
      <Test Name="Test5" Namespace="TestCases">
        <Parameters>
           <Parameter Type="Dev" Name="Dev">
               <Requirements>
                 <Requirement TypeId="a76" Source="User" />
                 <Requirement TypeId="2c9" Source="User" />
               </Requirements>
           </Parameter>
        </Parameters>
      </Test>
      <Test Name="Test6" Namespace="TestCases">
            <Parameters>
              <Parameter Type="Dev" Name="Dev">
                <Requirements>
                  <Requirement TypeId="a76" Source="User" />
                  <Requirement TypeId="2c9" Source="User" />
                </Requirements>
              </Parameter>
              <Parameter Type="Integer" Name="expected amount of images" Value="10" />
            </Parameters>
      </Test>
   </Children>
  </Group>
  <Models>
    <Model Name="DD1" />
  </Models>
</TestSuite>
```

So if you see in a.xml TestRoot Group, There are parameters defined which are also duplicated in other sub groups. I want to remove those groups and the duplicated parameters. I only want the first group "TestRoot" and a children tag containing all the test tags and the last model tag.

Click for the [Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/nbiE1ap)

I have this XSLT code which i tried but doesn't seems to be working.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="TestSuite/Group">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="Parameters"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="Children"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="TestSuite/Group/Children">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Group/Children/*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can anyone help me out here for achieving the output.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use

```
  <xsl:template match="Group[@Name = 'TestRoot']/Children">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select=".//Test"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

together with the identity transformation

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
 <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

as the base template.

I am not sure, however, I have understood the comment about duplicates, the above simply selects and processes any `test` descendants.